# check if the date is before the 5th of feb in iOS objective c

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

how can i check if the date entered by the date picker is before a certain day which is stored as a variable, the year does not matter.

for example, i need to check the date which is picked on the date picker to let me know if its before the 5th of January or after the 5th of January. the result should trigger an IF function if its true.

```
NSDate * dateOne = [NSDate date];
NSDate *dt1 = NSDate date];

if([dateOne compare:dateTwo] == NSOrderedAscending) {
    NSLog(@"TRUE");
}
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: '  NSDate * dateOne = [NSDate date];
    NSDate *dateTwo = [NSDate date];
    
    if([dateOne compare:dateTwo] == NSOrderedAscending) {
        NSLog(@"yes its further");
    }'

Comment: i am new to ios, still a bit stuck with how things work

Comment: That's ok. But give all the input you can when asking questions. Please read this. http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: 5th of current year or any year?

Comment: @Mugs now i create code which you want.. any years you select but if day and month is lessthan 5th feb then its not print "yes its further" otherwise its print.. try my code.. :)

Comment: I think he mean to say **Dates having the same year**... Just add condition for checking whether both dates have **same** year...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can get just date and month of selected date like bellow..

```
NSInteger sDay = [[[yourDatePicker date] stringFromDateWithFormat:@"dd"] integerValue];
NSInteger sMonth = [[[yourDatePicker date] stringFromDateWithFormat:@"MM"] integerValue];
if ( sMonth < 2 || (sMonth  == 2 && sDay < 5) ) {
        NSLog(@"yes its further");
}
```

And below is a method which you can use for convert any date with any date format.

```
-(NSString*)stringFromDateWithFormat:(NSString*)strDateFormat{
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
     //[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
    [formatter setDateFormat:strDateFormat];
    NSString *str = [formatter stringFromDate:self];
    [formatter release];
    return str;
}
```

Comment: Even 3Feb 2050 will be before 5th Feb? isn't an interesting question?

Comment: Using `NSDateFormatter` is a bit slow also this is what `NSDateComponents` is ment for.

Comment: yes mate first i think about that and first i post this above simple logic and after when came for post new code with NSDateFormatter then i see your answer.. but its also working right dude... :)

Comment: Your code will not work with any date past the 5th of january. since the day will be lager then 5 but the month will not be. So `6-jan-2013` will not pass your test.

Comment: worked great, but had to check the month first and then the date

Comment: @rckoenes try my code it will worked dude.. i check it out and also if its right then upvote me if its right.. :)

Comment: Your code still contains the bug, test it out with any date in january  after january 5th. I'm trying to help out.

Comment: @rckoenes thnx dude i know whats wrong here now i edit test my latest code... :)

Comment: @Mugs use this latest code with perfact condition which give you perfact output.. :)

Comment: @ParasJoshi Still not working for any dates after the 7th of January.  You need to split the month day check like I did my answer

Comment: @rckoenes now i see your code and also implement it see... :)

Comment: It needs to been `<5` not smaller then 6, since the date has to be before the 5th. Als now it's just my answer only then with the slow `NSDateFormatter`

Comment: @rckoenes its include 5th feb also in that condition i know about that its print that further in even 5th feb is selected and now its working...

Comment: @rckoenes now its working well i test it now with different date like 2 jan and 17 jan and 3 feb,etc..

Comment: No visible @interface for 'NSDate' declares the selector 'date'

Answer (score 4):

What you want to do is split up the the currect date in to [NSDateComponents](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

```
NSCalendar *currentCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [currentCalendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];

if (components.month < 2 || (components.month == 2 && components.day < 5) ){
    // Before the 5th of february.
}
```

Comment: Even 3Feb 2050 will be before 5th Feb? isn't an interesting question?

Comment: You are not checking on the year so yes. In my example I'm only checking if the month is lower then 2 and day is lower then 5 thus the date is before the 5th of february.